# Cannot find a initializer for type "UITableViewRowAction"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableviewrowaction

How come it keeping showing me this message even though I type the right declaration of `UITableViewRowAction`?

```
var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Share",
        handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode 6.4 documentation says both parameters should be implicitly unwrapped optionals.

```
var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Share",
        handler: { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
```

or in Xcode 7, neither parameters are optional.

```
var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Share",
        handler: { (action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in
```

---

Either way, you should try

```
var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Share") {
    action, indexPath in
    /* ... */
}
```

Which is a more swifty way of doing it.